# How to remove Management Menu on Kibana 7.8.1 Spaces and to make Dashboards page as principal?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I configured the space to only show Dashboard but the main Kibana screen is shown as well as the Management menu. How to make the main screen the Dashboard and the Management menu is no longer shown? thanks!

Kibana Home Screen:

[image: Kibana Home Screen]

---

Kibana Dashboard Screen:

[image: Kibana Dashboard Screen]

---

Kibana Management Menu:

[image: Kibana Management Menu]

Answer (score 0):

I got no "pro" solution for this as Spaces features are not very mature yet.

I use a little hack.

1. I create a user with minimal roles on one space and read on visualizations and dashboard in this space.
2. In my source app (website, intranet, etc...) I give the embedded link to a dashboard.

[image]
The url looks like this

```
/s/public/app/kibana#/dashboard/ab025da0-662a-11ea-9a69-7dafd55380b9?embed=true&_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-90d,to:now))&_a=(description:'',filters:!(),fullScreenMode:!f,options:(hidePanelTitles:!f,useMargins:!t),query:(language:kuery,query:''),timeRestore:!t,title:'Covid19%20-%20Dashboard%20(powered%20by%20Spoon%20Consulting)',viewMode:view)
```

Take the link from the iframe code and you'll have a clear dashboard without any header.
[image]

It's not secure at all. A user just have to clean up the url to have the home and access to the menu (but only with the rights his profile have)
But for most internal cases it do the job.

Comment: Hello @Ricardo, if my answer help you, please don't forget to validate it